# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error in COdeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When assigning a type casted array to codeigniter's session, I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Warning

Message: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Filename: libraries/Profiler.php

Line Number: 514
```

Code in question:

```
$guest = array('email' => 'empty', 'username' => 'Guest');
$this->session->set_userdata(array('current_user' => (object)$guest));
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well. for me it was having a `DateTime` object in my config variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CodeIgniter profiler breaks as soon as you store any non-array non-strings in its session:

```
foreach ($this->CI->session->all_userdata() as $key => $val)
{
    if (is_array($val))
    {
        $val = print_r($val, TRUE);
    }

    $output .= "<...>".htmlspecialchars($val)."<...>\n";
}
```

(from `CI_Profiler::_compile_session_data()`)

This looks like a pretty stupid thing since `print_r()` works fine with objects - so `is_array($val) || is_object($val)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: But it doesn't break when I use a object returned by a DB query. `$data = $this->db->get();` - `$userdata =  $data->result();` then `$this->session->set_userdata(array('current_user' => $userdata[0]));`

Comment: That's an array, not an object.

Comment: It is an stdClass object, `$userdata[0]` when printed displays as stdClass.

Comment: Only the top-level type matters, if it's an array `print_r()` will be used no matter what's inside that array.